# Oracle 11g startup and mount

Tags: oracle, startup, shutdown

When i stop Oracle 11g

```
SQL> shutdown immediate;
```

and i execute:

```
SQL> startup mount;
```

Error:

```
ORA-24324 service handle not initialized
ORA-01041: internal error, hostdef extension name not exists
```

Where's wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

fix it:

Connect to DB:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.1.0.6.0 - Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

```
SQL> shutdown immediate;
```

Database aready shutdown.

Aready uninstall database.

ORACLE instance aready close.

```
SQL> startup nomount;
```

ORA-12514: TNS: listner process can't recognize current service of connection describe string监听程序

```
SQL> startup nomount;
```

ORA-24324: service handle not initialized

ORA-01041: internal error, hostdef extension name not exists

```
SQL> conn sys/sys as sysdba;
```

Aready connect to idle instance

```
SQL> startup;
```

ORACLE instance started。

```
Total System Global Area  535662592 bytes
Fixed Size                  1334380 bytes
Variable Size             234881940 bytes
Database Buffers          293601280 bytes
Redo Buffers                5844992 bytes
```

Database loaded over

Answer (score 1):

You Can Simply Modify the ..\NETWORK\ADMIN\sqlnet.ora

make `SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (NULL)`

that  will  solve Your Problem